# HSTS preventing me from hitting local dev angular server with Firefox

Tags: angular, firefox, webpack-dev-server, self-signed, hsts

I have just started using angular via webpack to bring up a client webserver via

```
        "serve": {
                "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
                "options": {
                    "browserTarget": "myClientProject:build",
                    "proxyConfig": "./config/angular-proxy.conf.ts",
                    "port": 9006,
                    "host": "dev.mydomain.com",
                    "deployUrl": "",
                    "ssl": true
                },
```

When I try to hit the website via https://dev.mydomain:9006, Firefox gives me the error:

> **Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue**
> *Firefox detected a potential security threat and did not continue to dev.bulbapp.com because this website requires a secure connection.*
>
> *dev.mydomain.com has a security policy called HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS), which means that Firefox can only connect to it
> securely. You can’t add an exception to visit this site.*

And my only options are 'Go Back' and 'Advanced...'.  If I click 'Advanced', it doesn't allow me to ignore, or exclude, and just simply makes me go back.  According to one post I saw from Firefix, the HSTS protocol doesn't allow a browser to let a user override it, so therefore Firefox doesn't.

I used to use a grunt-connect server as my dev client server and never had this issue.  Now, after changing to using angular's server I can't get past the error.  Is there a way to disable HSTS in the angular server so that Firefox doesn't reject it?  Or bypass it some other way?

I read some posts regarding removing entries from the Firefox SiteSecurityServiceState.txt, but that didn't work.

I have tried to turn off SSL, but other portions of the project force HTTPS to be enabled.

I know that the webpack:dev-server actually allows a lot of options regarding HTTPS, but I don't know how to pipe those options through the custom-webpack:dev-server configuration to the standard webpack:dev-server.